# Not able to read custom data saved of google fit server

Tags: android, custom-data-type, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have successfully uploaded my custom data to google fit server. using following code.

```
        com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                        .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");
```

I found that also I can read custom data value within my app, but I am not getting it. Following is the code to retrieve it.

```
 final  PendingResult<DataTypeResult> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.readDataType(
                        mClient, "com.fitnessapi.custom_data_type");


                pendingResult.setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<DataTypeResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DataTypeResult dataTypeRes) {

                                DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);

                                List<DataPoint> points= dataSet.getDataPoints();

                                for(int i=0; i<points.size();i++)
                                {
                                   //Never getting values
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readDataType method will only return a dataType by name.

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/ConfigApi.html#readDataType)

Once it does you have to set a dataType variable to the results for use.

```
DataType dataTypeFromResult = dataTypeRes.getDataType();
```

Then pass it to what you need.

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(dataTypeFromResult)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

Comment: I was trying with aggregate parameter                          DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(dataSource, dataTypeFromResult)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

Comment: @Dhrupal Can you please let me know how to fetch the  fit data in android application

Comment: @Binod : Can you please ask question in different thread? I will ans in that.

Comment: @Dhrupal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234525/fetching-google-fit-data-into-android-application