# Fetching Google Fit Data into android application

Tags: android, google-fit

How can we get the data stored in google fit cloud for a specific user?
I tried using History API but no data is being displayed. Then i tried entering some data vai History api, now I could see these data only via history api not the complete data that actually resides in fit.

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();
DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Data Request is

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()

                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)

                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit

Comment: Yes The above code is from that only but some how it doesnot pull data from google fit cloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, it's hard to know what you're expecting but not receiving.  More detail would be helpful.

I'm guessing it's because Fit is returning the default merged stream of steps.  Basically, if two apps both report 1,000 steps for the same 60 minute period, Fit will assume that they're duplicative and "merge" them for the response.

Try losing the bucket function and see if you get the raw steps.  This code works for me:

```
    final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    DataSet stepData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);

    int totalSteps = 0;

    for (DataPoint dp : stepData.getDataPoints()) {
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            int steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt();

            totalSteps += steps;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your guess is correct because many steps are merges and so i was confused where does it lost. Thanks again

Comment: Does this solve the problem of not being able to read all Google Fit stored data?

Comment: I'm gonna answer my own question. yes it does

Answer (score 1):

Have you subscribe frist?
I have same issue but solved after `Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, myDataType)`

myDataType is `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA` or `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE`

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand how to insert the step counter value inside the insertFitnessData(). Basic History google program already has a DataSet that holds a step value of 1000. How should I change that part so it can count the steps that I am doing over the last hour?

```
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    // For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data  
    value -- in this case,
    // the number of new steps.
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Should I use the OnDataPointListener to recieve callbacks? I m confused!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data from the cloud, you must add following call to `DataReadRequest.Builder`: `enableServerQueries()`

So your code would then look like this:

```
final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can still use bucket, and it worked well until it didn't obey me at all. Anyway, I fixed it. There're some probable causes:

1) Have you subscribed this type of data yet?

2) Your app doesn't connect properly with google service. Have you created OAuth Client ID from Google develop console? This's compulsory in instruction of google to connect to its GG Fit service (Please notice that, if you clone another app, on the same computer or not, you need to re-create another OAuth Client ID and one more thing you need 2 separated account, one to login Google develop console to create OAuth Client ID and one to sign in after starting your app, and it will ask you to sign in to accept its permission,... not sure why it's is, but it would work)

Note: Btw you can make a search about Google setting in your device (Setting --> Google), Here you can find which app connects to google service (including GG Fit service). I recommend you disconnect all and delete OAuth Client ID, your app, then re-create all of them!

Mttdat.